# Input variables in Python 3

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

Is it possible to have a user input equal to a variable for tasks that involve chemical elements.

For example, Carbon has the molecular mass 12, but i do not want the use to input 12, They should input 'C'. but as the input turns this into a string, it is not possible to lik this to the variable  C = 12.

Is there any way to input a variable istead of a string?

If not, could i set a string as a variable.

example:

```
C = 12

element = input('element symbol:')
multiplier = input('how many?')

print(element*multiplier)
```

This just returns an error stating that you can't multiply by a string.

Comment: what are you expecting to an answer?

Comment: (off-topic) the molecular mass of carbon is 12.0107 g/mol, not 12.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change your code like this:

```
>>> masses = {'C': 12}
>>> element = input('element symbol:')
element symbol:C
>>> masses[element]
12
>>> multiplier = input('how many?')
how many?5
>>> multiplier
'5'                                          # string
>>> masses[element] * int(multiplier)
60
```

Answer (score 3):

[`input` in Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#input) is equivalent to `raw_input` in Python 2.x, i.e. it returns a string.

To evaluate that expression like Python 2.x's `input`, [use `eval`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#eval), as shown in the [doc for changes from 2.x to 3.0](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins).

```
element = eval(input("element symbol: "))
....
```

**However, `eval` allows execution of any Python code, so this could be very dangerous** (and slow). Most of the time you don't need the power of `eval`, including this. Since you are just getting a global symbol, you could use [the `globals()` dictionary](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#globals), and to convert a string into an integer, use [the `int` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#int).

```
element = globals()[input("element symbol: ")]
multiplier = int(input("how many? "))
```

but when a dictionary is needed anyway, why not restructure the program and store everything in a dictionary?

```
ELEMENTS = {'C': 12.0107, 'H': 1.00794, 'He': 4.002602, ...}

try:
  element_symbol = input("element symbol: ")
  element_mass = ELEMENTS[element_symbol]

  multiplier_string = input("how many? ")
  multiplier = int(multiplier_string)

  print(element_mass * multiplier)

# optional error handling
except KeyError:
  print("Unrecognized element: ", element_symbol)
except ValueError:
  print("Not a number: ", multiplier_string)
```

Comment: Do not use `eval()`, `globals()` here. Use `if element_symbol not in MASSES: ...`.

Comment: @JF: I agree on `eval` and `globals` which is why the final answer doesn't have these, but I disagree on `if element_symbol not in MASSES:` over exception handling. "It is Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission."

Answer (score 1):

Since input always return string type. Multiplication to the string is not allowed.
So after taking the `input`, you need to type cast if using `int` type in python .

Try this:

```
multiply_string = input("how many? ")
multiplier = int(multiplier_string) #type cast here as int
```

Answer (score 0):

element = eval(input("element symbol: "))

would be the simplest, but not necessarily the safest.  Plus, your symbol needs to be in the local scope

you might prefer to have a dictionary object